# a pattern for packing incoming parallel requests into one

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, design-patterns, parallel-processing

Suppose we have many randomly incoming threads accessing same resource in parallel. To access the resource thread needs to acquire a lock. If we could pack N incoming threads into one request resource usage would be N times more efficient. Also we need to answer individual request as fast as possible. What is the best way/pattern to do that in C#?

Currently I have something like that:

```
//batches lock
var ilock = ModifyBatch.GetTableDeleteBatchLock(table_info.Name);
lock (ilock)
{
    // put the request into requests batch
    if (!ModifyBatch._delete_batch.ContainsKey(table_info.Name))
    {
        ModifyBatch._delete_batch[table_info.Name] = new DeleteData() { Callbacks = new List<Action<string>>(), ids = ids };
    }
    else
    {
        ModifyBatch._delete_batch[table_info.Name].ids.UnionWith(ids);
    }
    //this callback will get called once the job is done by a thread that will acquire resource lock
    ModifyBatch._delete_batch[table_info.Name].Callbacks.Add(f =>
    {
        done = true;
        error = f;
    });
}

bool lockAcquired = false;
int maxWaitMs = 60000;
DeleteData _delete_data = null;

//resource lock
var _write_lock = GetTableWriteLock(typeof(T).Name);
try
{
    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
    while (!done)
    {
        lockAcquired = Monitor.TryEnter(_write_lock, 100);
        if (lockAcquired)
        {
            if (done) //some other thread did our job
                            {
                Monitor.Exit(_write_lock);
                lockAcquired = false;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        if ((DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds > maxWaitMs)
        {
            throw new Exception("Waited too long to acquire write lock?");
        }
    }
    if (done) //some other thread did our job
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
        {
            throw new Exception(error);
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    //not done, but have write lock for the table
    lock (ilock)
    {
        _delete_data = ModifyBatch._delete_batch[table_info.Name];
        var oval = new DeleteData();
        ModifyBatch._delete_batch.TryRemove(table_info.Name, out oval);
    }
    if (_delete_data.ids.Any())
    {
        //doing the work with resource 
    }
    foreach (var cb in _delete_data.Callbacks)
    {
        cb(null);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (_delete_data != null)
    {
        foreach (var cb in _delete_data.Callbacks)
        {
            cb(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    throw;
}
finally
{
    if (lockAcquired)
    {
        Monitor.Exit(_write_lock);
    }
}
```

Comment: "*If we could pack N incoming threads into one request resource usage would be N times more efficient*" - why is that?

Comment: @rustyx its because we have to maintain index (resource) and modification is cheaper in one iteration than in N iterations.

Comment: So... Many... Naming conventions. Be consistent, makes it easier for you (and others) to read/maintain

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 lol, bad habits stay long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is OK to process the task outside the scope of the current request, i.e. to queue it for later, then you can think of a sequence like this<sup>1</sup>:

Implement a resource *lock* (monitor) and a `List` of tasks.

1. For each request:
2. Lock the List, Add current task to the List, remember nr. of tasks in the List, unlock the List.
3. Try to acquire the *lock*.
4. If unsuccessful:

   - If the nr. of tasks in the list < threshold X, then Return.
   - Else Acquire the Lock (will block)
5. Lock the List, move it's contents to a temp list, unlock the List.
6. If temp list is not empty

   - Execute the tasks in the temp list.
   - Repeat from step 5.
7. Release the *lock*.

The first request will go through the whole sequence. Subsequent requests, if the first is still executing, will short-circuit at step 4.

Tune for the optimal threshold X (or change it to a time-based threshold).

---

<sup>1</sup> If you need to **wait** for the task in the scope of the request, then you need to extend the process slightly:

Add two fields to the Task class: *completion flag* and *exception*.

At step 4, before Returning, *wait* for the task to complete (`Monitor.Wait`) until its *completion flag* becomes `true`. If *exception* is not `null`, throw it.

At step 6, for each task, set the *completion flag* and optionally the *exception* and then *notify* the waiters (`Monitor.PulseAll`).

Comment: in my case request must wait until success/failure